# How to get the total amount of pages of a PDF file - iTextSharp, c#

Tags: c#, itext

I need help. I've spent last 4 hours trying to get the total amount of pages of my PDF file. I want to have something like "Page X/Y" in my footer. Can someone please tell me what to do with this code?

```
public class pdfPage : PdfPageEventHelper
{              
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {

        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle page = doc.PageSize;
        //PdfPTable EndTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPTable EndTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        EndTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 2f;
        EndTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
        iTextSharp.text.Font smallfont2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, "CP1250", 10);
        PdfPCell stopka1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Left column - not important", smallfont2));
        stopka1.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
        stopka1.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
        stopka1.BorderWidthRight = 0;
        stopka1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        stopka1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        PdfPCell stopka2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Page " + doc.PageNumber + "/", smallfont2));
        stopka2.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
        stopka2.BorderWidthBottom = 0;
        stopka2.BorderWidthRight = 0;
        stopka2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        stopka2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        EndTable.AddCell(stopka1);
        EndTable.AddCell(stopka2);
        EndTable.TotalWidth = page.Width - doc.LeftMargin - doc.RightMargin;
        EndTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.LeftMargin, EndTable.TotalHeight + doc.BottomMargin - 45, writer.DirectContent);

    }
   }
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I sorted it out. I simply closed the PDF file I was working on then copied it as a temporary file. Then in the method "OnEndPage" I counted pages in this temporary document. Later on, I opened a new document copied everything from this temporary, created an object of the pdfPage class and connected it to writer2.PageEvent. Now it works :)

Comment: You gave us your code (which is good).  But you have not explained in what sense your code has failed you (not so good).  Please elaborate on how exactly your existing code has failed you.

Comment: I don't know what to do now. I don't know how to get this "total number of pages of my PDF file" and put it here - PdfPCell stopka2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Page " + doc.PageNumber + "/", smallfont2));

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book). If you don't know where to start looking, check the [keywords](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php), more specifically: [Page X of Y](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=223).

There are two examples here:

- [MovieCountries1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) creates the PDF in one go, and adds the total number of page in the `onDocumentClose()` method, because, as you've already discovered, there is no way you or any type of software knows what the total number of pages will be before the document is closed.
- [TwoPasses](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118) creates the PDF in two passes, which is a much more robust solution than what you seem to have chosen as solution.

I'm sure you're tech-savvy enough to understand Java and to translate it to C#, but in case there are other people on SO who aren't, they can find the C# version of these examples [here](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH05) and [here](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH06).